# Why will my Insert Into statement not function properly

Tags: mysql

I am trying to follow along a YouTube guide on MySQL but when I try using `INSERT INTO`, I get the following **error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**. I am not sure why since I am following the guide exactly as it is. Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE student (
 student_id INT,
 name VARCHAR(20),
 major VARCHAR(20),
 PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
);


INSERT INTO student VALUES(1, 'jack', 'biology');
```

Comment: Your code works fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=616693e1727fc4f10b2be36431784054.

Comment: I tried testing it right now to confirm and I still get the same error. I am using DataGrip if that affects it.

Comment: Are you sure this is the CREATE statement? Try to list all the columns: `INSERT INTO student (student_id, name, major) VALUES(1, 'jack', 'biology');`

Comment: @forpas that solved my issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine (as I state in the comment).

But I do have comments about your code.

- Often, a table's id would be assigned automatically.
- The list of columns should be included in the `insert`.

So, I would write the code as:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    student_id INT auto_increment primary key,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    major VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO student (name, major)
    VALUES ('jack', 'biology');
```

Listing the columns explicitly will help prevent the problem that you are getting when you write code in the future.  My guess is that you left a column out of the table definition.